# Changing ContextMenuStrip background

Tags: .net, vb.net, skinning

is it possible to change Background of `ContextMenuStrip`? I was trying to do that using `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` but i cant find right method/option to do so and MS documentation is not really helpfull. Im able to change only Item Background at the moment which is not enough for what I want to achiev.

Im trying to reskin that component to look like this:

[image: Skined ContextMenu]

So i want to have transparency, custom background with rounded corners. Can `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` do theese changes? Or would I need something else (what)?

Comment: In a Windows Forms Application this would be very difficult. The example given I looks like some WPF / XAML. So which do you want to use?

Comment: Exactly that i need - Windows Form Aplication using VB.Net ... sadly "It will be difficult" I already figured out, would be nice to see some solution now :)

Comment: You can change the BG color just by changing....the BackColor property. The `ToolStripProfessionalRenderer` can be used to change parts of the menu very easily.  Perhaps you should share your code you tried and the specifics

Comment: As i written before, i would like to use as background "sliced" image so i would need to find in Renderer (if it suffice for my purpose) method responsible for drawing background part of context menu (and draw + position there parts of my image myself)  and I did not find any. So if you know which metod if I would leave blank will result in transparent (background of) Context Menu let me please know.